# Determining destination of JMS Message with AspectJ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, aop, aspectj

I've created the following pointcut for calls to javax.jms.MessageProducer.send(..):

```
pointcut callJmsSend(Message message): 
   (call(void javax.jms.MessageProducer.send(javax.jms.Message)))
   && args(message);
```

which works fine. I have both a before and after advice for this pointcut which (amongst other things) reads the JmsDestination property.

```
before(Message message): callJmsSend(message) {
    // null pointer exception
    String queueName = message.getJMSDestination().toString();
}

after(Message message): callJmsSend(message) {
    // works
    String queueName = message.getJMSDestination().toString();
}
```

Reading the JavaDoc for getDestination() reveiled that the property is set after send() is called.

> Gets the Destination object for this message.
> The JMSDestination header field contains the destination to which the message is being >sent.
>
> When a message is sent, this field is ignored. After completion of the send or publish >method, the field holds the destination specified by the method.

Is there some other way I can access the JmsDestination within the before advice?

edit:
Perhaps useful info: I'm using ActiveMQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem:

```
MessageProducer producer = (MessageProducer)thisJoinPoint.getTarget();
String queueName = producer.getDestination().toString();
```